# Cannot retrieve data on S3 Bucket from a deployed lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await, aws-sdk-nodejs

I invoke a step function from a lambda function, that processes data and stores them in a S3 bucket. From within this lambda function I tried to download the data but I am getting an error message with "AccessDenied" (see further below).

If I run this lambda function a second time, I do not get any error and the execution terminates successfully. My understanding is that during the first run, the data are not yet stored while I am trying to download them, which would explain why on my second try this is working good.

I am using the pair `async/await` thinking that this would be enough to hold the execution while waiting for the data to be stored. Is there something I am not doing correctly?

Here is an extract of the code (step function not detailed here):

```
async function downloadData(){
    var rawData = await s3.getObject({Bucket: 'myBucket/', Key: 'myData.json'}).promise();
    var data = JSON.parse(rawData.Body.toString('utf-8'));
    return data;
}

async function invokeStepFunction(){
    const stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();
    var params = {
        stateMachineArn: process.env.state_machine_arn,
        input: JSON.stringify({"Bucket": 'myBucket/'})
    };
    await stepfunctions.startExecution(params).promise();
}

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: process.env.region});
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await invokeStepFunction();
    const data = await downloadData();
    console.log(data);
}
```

and this is the error message:

```
{"errorType":"AccessDenied","errorMessage":"AccessDenied","code":"AccessDenied","message":"AccessDenied","region":null,"time":"2020-03-25T13:13:20.832Z","requestId":"...","extendedRequestId":"...","statusCode":403,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":91.97041111587372,"stack":["AccessDenied: Access Denied","    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:816:35)","    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)","    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)","    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)","    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)","    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"]}
```

Comment: Logging the s3 object might help you see if there is any difference in first time execution & the later ones.

Comment: @AmitaMohite Thanks. I can see on the logs that on the first run, the data are not there yet when I try to download them (the download looks like two seconds too fast). For the second execution, the data are already there, because of the first execution - this is the reason why it is working. By naming my data to upload/download with a timestamp, no execution is working: when asking for the download the data are still not there.

Comment: I meant, log the s3 object. In this case the object variable "s3".   It will have various fields like region, permissions etc.   See if you find any difference in first time execution & later one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you await the step function `startExecution` invocation, you are waiting for AWS Step Functions to indicate that it has received your request to begin execution of the Step Function. It does *not* indicate that the Step Function has itself run to completion.

So, you're executing `downloadData` before the Step Function actually stored the data in S3, and the file does not exist in S3 first time around. When you call it later, that `downloadData` appears to succeed but it is almost certainly downloading the object *previously* stored in S3 (from the first run).

You need to execute your download step sometime after the download has actually happened. You could, for example, make the download an additional step at the end of the upload Step Function.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. I've solved this by setting a timeout, which gave enough time for the data to actually be uploaded before the download.

Comment: That could work well for small objects. I wouldn't rely on it for large objects, however, as they may fail to download in time plus your Lambda sleeping for minutes is costing you money unnecessarily. If my answer explained the problem you were having then please consider accepting it.